# Линия из 10px Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow

Есть код:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
img = Image.open('image.png')
a = np.asarray(img)
```

Нужно пройтись по изображению и найти все горизонтальные линии одного цвета шириной от 1px и длиной от 10px. Как это сделать? Желательно привести пример

Comment: @insolor, по-моему, вопросы разные, в том, что вы привели задается про количество пикселей определенного цвета, а в этом про нахождение подряд идущих пикселей одного цвета

Comment: @gil9red, да, пожалуй соглашусь. Отозвал голос за закрытие.

Comment: @Vecher, если работать через `PIL.Image`, то можно запросить пиксели по индексам, для этого есть `img.size` --для получения значения ширины и высоты, и `img.getpixel((x, y))` для получения пикселя в определенном месте ([простой пример](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/8f27b7807258a63fa2da1254647bf4245cf2c67c/pil_pillow__examples/for_cycle__pixels__array/main.py#L21)). Задача сводится к перебору пикселей в цикле значений ширины и высоты. Для решения с `numpy` будет тот же цикл и перебор `a`

Comment: @gil9red Спасибо! Сейчас попробую